# how to Gridstack Set the height of each grid based on their inner contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridstack

In Gridstack i need to Set the height of each grid based on their inner contents! but i tried many way. I want to set the height of each grid based on their inner contents, i do not want any scroll bar. i have tried but i can't get result, there have any way.. to do this.